# How to check if a picture was taken by the user or not

Tags: file-upload, camera, image, exif, image-uploading

I've recently run into some trouble in a Web app I'm developing. In this Web app I allow users to upload pictures and I need to check -to a certain extent- that the pictures they upload were taken from their own cameras, webcams, mobile devices, etc.
If I can't guarantee that the image being uploaded "belongs" to the user (*e.g.* was downloaded from somewhere on the internet, made in Paint, etc.) the file is discarded, otherwise it is stored.

I know any method to implement this will be highly inaccurate and will produce many false positives -or negatives- and that there is no bulletproof solution, but I'm just looking for a tentative way to do it.

So far I've thought of

- checking if the picture has [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data present and if so, if it's
  date is relatively recent, store it
- providing the option to take "snapshots" from the user's webcam like [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/) does
  for the profile picture

Are there any other ways to do this?